# DateRangeInput problem. Can't implement the ggplot

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to show Imports and Exports by Years in my country. I have a dateRangeInput which allows to choose the years. 
However, I don't know how to filter the input.

I tried this

```
 df2 <- df[as.Date(df$Year) > input$dateRange[1] &
              as.Date(df$Year) < input$dateRange[2],]
```

This is in my UI

```
dateRangeInput("dateRange", label = 'Date Range', format = "yyyy-mm-dd", 
                     startview = "year", start = '2009-01-01', end='2017-01-01',
                     min = df$Year[1], max = df$Year[9])
```

And this is the SERVER part

```
output$retail = renderPlotly({
  df1 <- reactive({
    filter(df, between(df$Year ,input$daterange[1], input$daterange[2]))
  })

    ggplot(df1(), aes(x = Year)) + 
      geom_line(aes(y = Export.TOTAL), color = "#FF7954") + 
      geom_line(aes(y = Import.TOTAL), color= "#3639e2") +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FF5733"), name = "Type")+
      labs(title = "Balance of Import/Export", y =" " ) +
      theme_minimal() +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2009,2017)) +
      )
  })
```

I expect a graph that shows the Import/Export results between the chosen dates.

Answer (score 0):

From this issue, https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1639, `between()` is expecting numeric values. It seems if you wrap `as.Date()` around the values, it should work.